# How to export TypeScript or JavaScript into a YAML list

Tags: javascript, typescript, yaml

I would like to reference a Typescript file that exports an object as a list of mappings in a YAML file.

So far, I figured out how to insert mappings using a JS file that routes to an exported Typescript object with the following code:

```
//YAML file
functions:
  - ${file(./functions.js):functions}
```

```
// functions.js
require('ts-node').register({module: "commonjs"});
require('tsconfig-paths').register();

module.exports.functions = (serverless) => {
  return {

    FunctionOne     : require('@src/file/path/File').config,
 }
}
```

```
// File.ts

export const config = any => {
  const configs: any = {
    ex1: 'Key Value',
    ex2: [{
      ex3: {
        foo: 'Value',
        bar: '1234',
      }
    }],
    // --- cut remaining mappings
  };
  return configs;
};
```

However, this method doesn't work for the following example, where instead I'd like to have the file turn:

```
models:
   - name: Model1
     contentType: "application/json"
     schema: ${file(./Model1.json)}

   - name: Model2
     contentType: "application/json"
     schema: ${file(./Model2.json)}
```

into

```
models:
   - ${file(./models.js):models
```

with a similarly formatted JS file with references to the model setup.

Comment: Sorry, the term I mean is a mapping. I am looking to make a list of mappings.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. I don't know the answer (for doing that in TypeScript), but I am sure the change helps someone who does to unambigiously understand what you want.